# Exclude certain numbers from range of numbers using Regular expression

Tags: regex, webmethods

Could some one help me with the regular expression, where we can exclude certain numbers in between from a range of numbers.

Presently, `^([1-9][0][0-9])$` is the regular expression that is configured. Now if i want to exclude a few numbers/one number(`501`,`504`) from it, then how would the regular expression look/be.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Described in more detail [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/406408/1380781), you can use the following regex with the “Negative Lookahead” command `?!`:

```
^((?!501|504)[0-9]*)$
```

You can see the regex being executed & explained here: https://regex101.com/r/mL0eG4/1

> /^((?!501|504)[*0-9*]*)$/mg
>
> - ^ assert position at start of a line
> - 1st Capturing group ((?!501|504)[0-9]*)
>
>   - (?!501|504) Negative Lookahead - Assert that it is impossible to match the regex below
>
>     - 1st Alternative: 501
>
>       - 501 matches the characters 501 literally
>     - 2nd Alternative: 504
>
>       - 504 matches the characters 504 literally
>   - [0-9]* match a single character present in the list below
>
>     - Quantifier: * Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
>     - 0-9 a single character in the range between 0 and 9
> - $ assert position at end of a line
> - m modifier: **m**ulti-line. Causes ^ and $ to match the begin/end of each line (not only begin/end of string)
> - g modifier: **g**lobal. All matches (don't return on first match)